# Unable to get tab items in a common function when called from UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I've a common function in `UIViewController` extension. I'm calling this function from tab bar controller and view controller. This works when called from view controller but doesn't work when called from tab bar controller. Control goes to **else Error: tabItems**. I can't figure out what's wrong, any other way of doing it so that it works when called from tab controller?

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.updateBadges()
}

extension UIViewController {

    func updateBadges() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setBadge(tab: 1, count: 3)
        }
    }

    func setBadge(tab: Int, count: Int) {
        if let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
            print("Inside tabItems")

            let tabItem = tabItems[tab]

            if count != 0 {
                tabItem.badgeValue = String(count)
            } else {
                tabItem.badgeValue = nil
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: tabItems")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the extension need not to be for `UIViewController ` as the code is related to `UITabBarController` and making it ` tabController extension , you can access it like this inside any tab `self.tabBarController?.setBadge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `self.tabBarController` is `nil` for the `UITabBarController` itself. One possible solution is something like the following:

```
func setBadge(tab: Int, count: Int) {
    let tabBarController = self as? UITabBarController ?? self.tabBarController

    if let tabItems = tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
        print("Inside tabItems")

        let tabItem = tabItems[tab]

        if count != 0 {
            tabItem.badgeValue = String(count)
        } else {
            tabItem.badgeValue = nil
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: tabItems")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. So how do I go about fixing this? Shall I check which type of vc has called and then modify code accordingly?

Comment: You saved me from having sleepless night :) Tx.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just wanted to say that you should think about @matt's answer nevertheless. But it got deleted in this moment. :)

Comment: if eventually be casted then better as `extension UITabBarController `

Comment: @Sh_Khan If he extends `UITabBarController` he can't call the function from "regular" `UIViewController` subclasses. And that's what he was looking for.

Comment: he can `self.tabBarController?.setBadge`

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry. Missed that. Already past midnight here in germany... ;)